# R Shiny - Check to see if tab exists before doing an insertTab

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here is a minimum reproducible Shiny app. When you click "GO TO NEXT SCREEN" it creates a new tab in the tabset using `insertTab`. But then, if you click back to the "Survey Questions" tab, when you click "GO TO NEXT SCREEN" it creates a second tab (which is bad).

How can I check to see if `contacttab` exists before I attempt to `insertTab`? Thanks for any suggestion. (I have tried `shinyjs::disable`, `shinyjs::toggle` and `shinyjs::toggleState` unsuccessfully.)

```
library(shiny)  
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Check to See if Tab Exists"),
    sidebarPanel(
        h2("My Sidepanel"),
        tags$a("Brought to you by Stack Overflow", href="http://stackoverflow.com"), width=3
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(id="maintabset",     
          tabPanel(title="Survey Questions", value="surveytab", fluid=TRUE,
             HTML("<h4><font color='blue'>Stuff on my Survey Tab</font></h4>"),
             h4("... more stuff ..."),
             actionBttn(inputId="gotonext", label="GO TO NEXT SCREEN", color="success", 
                        style="material-flat", block=TRUE)
          ) # end tabpanel
        ) # end tabsetpanel
    ) #end mainpanel
))

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$gotonext, {
    # I ONLY WANT TO INSERTTAB IF CONTACTTAB DOES NOT EXIST YET
       insertTab(inputId = "maintabset", 
         tabPanel(title="Contact Information", value="contacttab", 
              textInput("email", label=h4("Email:"), value="Enter your email...") 
         ), #endtabpanel
        target="surveytab", position="after",
       ) # end inserttab

    # ... but I always want clicking "GO TO NEXT" button to put focus on contacttab
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "maintabset", selected="contacttab")
    })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input "email" will exist only if you create the new tab (hence only if you click on the button), you can detail some conditions based on this input inside `observeEvent`: if this input does not exist (i.e if you never clicked on the button), then a new tab is created; if this input already exists (i.e you already clicked on the button) then you are automatically redirected to this tab.

```
library(shiny)  
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Check to See if Tab Exists"),
  sidebarPanel(
    h2("My Sidepanel"),
    tags$a("Brought to you by Stack Overflow", href="http://stackoverflow.com"), width=3
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id="maintabset",     
                tabPanel(title="Survey Questions", value="surveytab", fluid=TRUE,
                         HTML("<h4><font color='blue'>Stuff on my Survey Tab</font></h4>"),
                         h4("... more stuff ..."),
                         actionBttn(inputId="gotonext", label="GO TO NEXT SCREEN", color="success", 
                                    style="material-flat", block=TRUE)
                ) # end tabpanel
    ) # end tabsetpanel
  ) #end mainpanel
))

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$gotonext, {
    if(is.null(input$email)){
      insertTab(inputId = "maintabset", 
                tabPanel(title="Contact Information", value="contacttab", 
                         textInput("email", label=h4("Email:"), value="Enter your email...") 
                ), 
                target="surveytab", position="after", select = TRUE
      )
    }
    else{
     updateTabsetPanel(session, "maintabset", selected="contacttab")
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Also, you need to add `select = TRUE` in `insertTab` so that the created tab is automatically selected.